# Laravel Ajax login, redirect to previous url after success

Tags: ajax, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

Suppose I have a page A where auth middleware is being used. Because of no login it gets redirected to login page.

On login page I have custom ajax login system. On succesful login I want to redirect to page A with same url so that action can be completed.

My code for login is like this:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{

    $auth = false;
    $errors = [];

    $inputs = $request->all();
    $validator = $this->validator($inputs);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'auth' => false,
            'intended' => URL::previous(),
            'errors' => $validator->errors()
        ]);
    }

    $user = User::where('email', $request->get('email'))->first();

    if ($user && $user->is_active == 0) {
        $errors[] = "This account has been deactivated";
    } else if ($user && $user->confirm_token != null) {
        $errors[] = "Please verify your email in order to login";
    } else {

        $credentials = ['email' => $request->get('email'), 'password' => $request->get('password'), 'is_active' => 1];

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            $auth = true;
        } else {
            $errors[] = "Email/Password combination not correct";
        }

    }

    if ($request->ajax()) {          
        return response()->json([
            'auth' => $auth,
            'intended' => URL::previous(),
            'errors' => $errors
        ]);
    }

    return redirect()->intended(URL::route('dashboard'));

}
```

I am trying to get previous url through url()->previous() but it returns login page url. Can someone guide me in this please. Any improvements/help will be appreciated.

I am using Laravel 5.4

Comment: Idk if my way is right but I do this totally different way. I don't use ajax() I just pass values like on post without ajax and return errors or redirect...

Comment: Use back() and pass it as text

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: do it with session. whenever login middleware denies access you can put it in session with a certain key. and whenever user logged in successfully redirect to that route and clear the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by making a hidden field in form containing url()->previous() value because no other way I was getting previous page i.e Page A url. I tried almost all above answers.

Answer (score 7):

I have a very similar problem here: [Ajax Auth redirect on Laravel 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873624/ajax-auth-redirect-on-laravel-5-6)

As @aimme (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1409707/aimme) pointed out, Ajax calls are stateless, so basically you can't interact with backend.

His suggestion and my suggestion is to pass in the URL the intended page to redirect to, or maybe in your case you could to it via post parameters, e.g.:

```
return response()->json([
    'auth' => false,
    'intended' => $request->intended,
    'errors' => $validator->errors()
]);
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to do anything special for AJAX calls.

Redirect the same way you normally would on the back-end after a form submission.

```
return redirect()->route('dashboard');
```

On the front-end you just need to be sure that you use the redirected URL to change the `window.location`. This will cause the browser to refresh and go to the new page.

```
axios.post(url, formData).then(response => {
    window.location = response.request.responseURL;
});
```

This code snippet is for the popular [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library but the same thing can be done with jQuery or vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

It might help you

Instead of these `return redirect()->intended(URL::route('dashboard'));`

use

```
return redirect('dashboard');
```

Comment: I am talking about AJAX request part

Comment: He needs to set the page dynamically based on where he was.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 5.4 + support . not know for lower version

```
 return redirect()->back();
```

This will redirect to previous page from where you came .

Ajax part

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "<?php echo url()->previous(); ?>";
    location.href = url;
 </script>

                OR simply javascript function
 history.go(-1);
```

Check for above and working fine for me please check for your code .

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, the problem is that you're confusing the *previous* URL for the *intended* URL when you're trying to provide a URL to redirect to in your JSON response. The *previous* URL actually refers to the [HTTP Referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer), not the intended URL, which is set in the session by Laravel's auth middleware.

The HTTP referrer is the page that initiates a request. If you are currently on page `/foo` and you click a link to a page `/bar`, the HTTP Referrer on `/bar` will be `/foo`. The same thing happens when you initiate an AJAX request, the page you're on will be the referrer of the end point you're hitting. In your case your login page is initiating the request to your login handler, via AJAX.

When you try to visit a page protected by Laravel's auth middleare, it is at that point Laravel sets a value for the *intended* URL in the session, before redirecting you to the login page. Laravel stores the *intended* URL in the session as `url.intended` (As you will be able to see in `Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::intended`, which is what `redirect()->intended()` calls). So all you need to do is grab that from the session.

```
if ($request->ajax()) {          
    return response()->json([
        'auth' => $auth,
        'intended' => session()->pull('url.intended') ?: URL::route('dashboard'),
        'errors' => $errors
    ]);
}

return redirect()->intended(URL::route('dashboard'));
```

**Note:** Using `->pull` will remove the item from the session after it has been retrieved.

An easier way to do this would be just to grab the target URL from an intended `RedirectResponse`:

```
$redirect = redirect()->intended(URL::route('dashboard'))

if ($request->ajax()) {          
    return response()->json([
        'auth' => $auth,
        'intended' => $redirect->getTargetUrl(),
        'errors' => $errors
    ]);
}

return $redirect;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
URL::previous();
```

this method will help you get previous URL. and you can redirect user to there using jQuery somelike this:

```
window.location.href = url; // <- you can try your url here.
```

Good Luck !!

Comment: He stated in his post that URL::previous(); isn't working for him. 
The jquery code for redirecting works, but url isn't defined in your example. 

It's not clear what he should be doing from reading this answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you got a request in backend save the redirect()->intended();

> intended() checks if the session index url.intended exists and
>   redirects to it by default or else redirect to $default='/' which can
>   be overwritten.

then pass this URL when request success, example:

```
function testAjax(handleData) {
  $.ajax({
    url:"getvalue.php",  
    success:function(data) {
      window.location.href = data.url;
    }
  });
}
```