# Ajax Auth redirect on Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.6

I have a Like button that fires an Ajax Post, this route is protected by auth:api middleware:

myproject/routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::post('/v1/like', 'APIController@set_like');
});
```

When an authenticated user clicks the like button, no problem at all, everything works smoothly. But when guests click the button, I redirected them to login page via Javascript and after authentication they are redirected to the page specified in RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware, so usually to /home.
I modified that middleware as follows:

myproject/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect()->intended('/home');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My Ajax call is this:

```
var toggleLike = function(){
    var token = USER_TOKEN; //javascript variable
    var current_type = $(thisLikeable).attr("data-type");
    var current_id = $(thisLikeable).attr("data-id");
    var jqxhr = $.post( APP_URL + "/api/v1/like", {api_token: token, type: current_type, id: current_id}, function(data) {
        setLikeAppearance(data.message);
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error){
        if (xhr.status == 401) {
            window.location = APP_URL + "/login" ;
        }
    });
};
```

The problem here's the intended() function, which for Ajax calls is not storing the correct session variable and I am not figuring out how to set it properly.
I am clearly missing something obvious, can anyone help?
Cheers!

**EDIT**

What I want to achieve is this:

1. GUEST is in //mysite/blabla
2. clicks Like button
3. gets redirected to login
4. logs in (or register)
5. gets redirected to //mysite/blabla with the Like already triggered on

Comment: there will be no session on api. because it's sateless.

Comment: Yep, but there must be a way to handle this..

Comment: just send a 401 response from api. than you need to handle it from frontend

Comment: don't redirect from api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that in APIs sessions are not managed or in other words it's stateless. So the session middleware is not implemented on Laravel framework for API requests. Though you can manually add, it's not idle to use. So if the API does not use sessions and uses the redirect, fronted does not know about it, as API and frontend work as two separate apps. SO you need to send the frontend the status of the response and let the frontend handle the redirect as you have done with ajax. Just remove the redirect if unauthenticated and let the API throw unauthorized exception. Then, from the handler, handle the unauthorized exception.

Here is how to do it.

Add this to **app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

```
/**
 * Convert an authentication exception into an unauthenticated response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest('login');
}
```

this will send the user a 401 with message Unauthenticated if the request was json(api request), else(if web request) will redirect to login

check the `render` method below or check it from [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L167) to understand what's happening. when an unauthorized exception is thrown we are telling to check the request type and if it's from an API request, we are sending a json response with 401 status code. So know from frontend we could redirect the user to login page after seeing the 401 status code.

**From source**

```
/**
 * Render an exception into a response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if (method_exists($e, 'render') && $response = $e->render($request)) {
        return Router::toResponse($request, $response);
    } elseif ($e instanceof Responsable) {
        return $e->toResponse($request);
    }
    $e = $this->prepareException($e);
    if ($e instanceof HttpResponseException) {
        return $e->getResponse();
    } elseif ($e instanceof AuthenticationException) {
        return $this->unauthenticated($request, $e);
    } elseif ($e instanceof ValidationException) {
        return $this->convertValidationExceptionToResponse($e, $request);
    }
    return $request->expectsJson()
                    ? $this->prepareJsonResponse($request, $e)
                    : $this->prepareResponse($request, $e);
}
```

**AFTER EDIT**

The intended `method()` is only for web routes as it uses session to extract the intended route or manually passed value. Here is the intended() method.

```
/**
 * Create a new redirect response to the previously intended location.
 *
 * @param  string  $default
 * @param  int     $status
 * @param  array   $headers
 * @param  bool    $secure
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function intended($default = '/', $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
{
    $path = $this->session->pull('url.intended', $default);

    return $this->to($path, $status, $headers, $secure);
}
```

To achive the redirect to the page the user is comming from you can

1 - Manually pass some queries with url  like 
`/login?redirect=like(not the url, just a mapping for /comments/like url)&value=true(true is liked, false is unliked)`
 and handle it manually.

2 - Get and check the query parameters from url

3 - Use to() method to pass the intended url instead of using intended(). here is the to() method. (see 4 to see the recommended way)

```
/**
 * Create a new redirect response to the given path.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  int     $status
 * @param  array   $headers
 * @param  bool    $secure
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function to($path, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
{
    return $this->createRedirect($this->generator->to($path, [], $secure), $status, $headers);
}
```

4 - But, I would recommend sending redirect url (I mean the mapping ex: like) as a response to frontend and let the frontend handle the redirecting. As API redirecting will work if the API is used by websites only. Suppose if you are using this same api for a mobile app, wonder how API redirect will work. It's not a work of API to redirect, unless if it's for things like OAuth Authentication, which would have a redirect url specified.

> Remember to sanitize the url params to block XSS like stuff. Better
>   Send some values and map it to the urls. Like
>
> ```
> [
>    //like is mapping
>    //comments/like is the actual url
>
>    'like' => 'comments/like'
> ]
> ```
>
> Then, get the mapping url from array or use frontend mappings.

Comment: I can't understand. In my Javascript I am already getting error 401, my problem is that I want users to log in if they click the button, and get redirected to the original page in which they clicked the button. So that's why I initially used the intended() method.

Comment: intended() works only with sessions. so intended() can't be used for api calls. you should pass the url as url query, manually validate it sanitize it and send it to to() method manually instead of intended() method. first parameter is the intended url.

Comment: I got your point, if I set the parameter in the URL directly and then handle it in the redirect, it should work. To be honest setting the parameters in the URL is not the best solution, but if I don't find anything else I'll use your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: see the edit. ya do not add the whole url as the query, just use mapping as I have mentioned in the edit.

Comment: I upvoted your suggestion because it's very rich and detailed, many thanks!  I am still not convinced of passing parameters to the URL because it opens gates to maliciousness, so I'll wait if someone else had the same problem and solved with a simpler solution ;) Thanks again!

Comment: Ya. Same here. see the edit now. I wouldn't recommend redirecting from api at all. See the 4th point. use mapping at frontend, send the response to frontend and let frontend handle the redirect.

Comment: Thank you. I have cleaned the url query params to make it understandable. it's not the urls directly, its just the mapping, i assumed /comments/like is the url as an example. :)

Comment: In the end, since using Ajax means statelessness, as you correctly suggested there's no backend solution. Funny thing is that before using Laravel I considered myself a front-end developer :P thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can make changes in your **RedirectIfAuthenticated.php** to distinguish between **Ajax** call & normal login like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

            if ($request->has('api_token')) {
                // do whatever you want

                return response()->json('some response'); 
            }

                return redirect()->intended('/home');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Another solution is to remove **Auth** middleware from your route. In **APIController@set_like** function manually login user, trigger like & return json response.

Comment: Since I am invoking the authentication through this:


          window.location = APP_URL + "/login" ;


It's not an Ajax call.

Comment: Removing the Auth middleware is not a solution, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

If a button is not for a guest, then you shouldn't render it on page.
Instead, you should render a link to login, then if the user logs in you will redirect him back to where he was before. Now, user can see and click the button.

Comment: This is more a UI/UX decision, in my case I prefer to show the users the original action and encourage them to join.

Comment: So, you can handle it on your JavaScript side.
If you recieve a 401 status code, then maybe show a popup modal to login, if the login is successful, then you try again the ajax request. I think there is no other way to handle this on laravel side. I&#39;m not sure